# Pseudo convex quadratic forms are quasi convex

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

[image: Bela Matros, Subdefinite matrices and quadratic forms, 1969]

I have been trying to show: A Pseudoconvex quadratic form is Quasiconvex in the same set X, by using the following definitions. These definitions are equivalent to the standard definitions of Pseudo and Quasiconvexity of the quadratic forms. In the proof lemma 8, it is written that this follows from continuity. I am not able to understand how to use continuity to prove this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understood by going through some texts on convexity that the continuity the author is talking about is the continuity of the Quadratic form due to which all the different type of strict and non-strict convexities coincides in a way. And that makes the above lemma to be true trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Q$ is Pseudoconvex and let $x$ and $y$ be in $X$.

If $x'Cx-y'Cy >0$, then by pseudoconvexity of $Q$, it follows that $(x-y)'Cx > 0$.

Suppose $x'Cx-y'Cy =0$. Assume on the contrary that $(x-y)'Cx < 0$, i.e $x'Cx-y'Cx<0$. So

$$(x-y)'C(x-y) = x'Cx+y'Cy-2y'Cx = 2x'Cx-2y'Cx <0$$
Therefore 
$$0'C0-(x-y)'C(x-y)>0$$
By the pseudoconvexity of $Q$, it follows that
$$(0-x+y)'C0>0$$
i.e $$0>0$$
Which is absurd.
Hence $(x-y)'Cx \ge 0$ i.e $Q$ is Quasiconvex.